# Auto-add quotes around new lines in VS Code like Netbeans does

Tags: netbeans, visual-studio-code

Just about completed my transition from Netbeans to VS Code, and there's one thing missing from VS Code that I miss dearly from Netbeans that essentially handles quotes automatically when you press enter from within a string.

These pictures should show what I mean, with this first picture being a lengthy string inside of Netbeans.

[image: Netbeans long text string before]

And this one is after I press enter somewhere in the middle of the string without pressing any other keys

[image: Netbeans after enter key]

You can see that it puts a quote where the cursor was, adds a newline, adds indentation, adds a dot (the PHP concat operator), and then another quote, which is such a fantastic feature.

Two things; what is this called, and how do I get this behavior in VS Code?

Comment: I'm looking for an extension to do exactly this, but couldn't find any. Strange thing is that Visual Studio (non-Code) has exactly this functionality, at least for C#. Maybe even for other languages too, don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy to do with a macro.  Install the [macrosRE extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l7ssha.macrosRe).

In your settings.json:

```
"macros": {

 "netbeans": [
      {
      "command": "type",
      "args": {
        "text": "\"\n\t\t. \""
      }
    }    
  ]
},
```

and set up some keybinding for it in keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "macros.netbeans"
  },
```

It would really interesting if there was a "`when`" condition to detect if within a string (and within a php file) ...and then bind to <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  But I doubt there is such a "`when`" clause.

[**EDIT**]:

I should have remembered that in your case the 'macro' is so simple that you don't need to use the macro functionality.  Try simply this in your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+alt+n",
    "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    //"when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == php",
    //"when": "editorTextFocus && resourceLangId == php"
    "args": {
      "snippet": "\"\n\t\t. \""
    }
}
```

It just inserts a snippet which is right there in the args.  You may or may not want the 'php' limitation.  You can also use the method below if you want to insert a snippet that actually lives in a snippets file:

```
{
  "key": "cmd+k 1",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "langId": "csharp",
    "name": "myFavSnippet"
  }
}
```

From [vscode doc: assigning a keybinding to a snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets).

But you will eventually want to chain commands together which the macros extension allows you to do.

Comment: That's what I was worried about, since the Netbeans way does it with just the enter key, it's aware of the current language you're in (especially with PHP since the file can - and does - contain JS, HTML, PHP, etc.), which changes the concat operator

Comment: Macros work pretty well, wasn't sure how I'd feel about this solution but after spending a day with it, it feels pretty good, especially since I only really end up needing this in PHP anyway